# Android Studio / Error al abrir mi app (Acceso denegado)

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy trabajando hace aproximadamente 1 mes en mi aplicación hasta que hoy ya no puedo emularla más en mi dispositivo físico. Este problema ocurrió justo después de haber actualizado windows 7 a windows 10.

**Adjunto el error:**

```
C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\LearnIn\app\build\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\signing-config.json (Acceso denegado)
```

**------------------------**

```
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: 1 exception was raised by 
workers:
A failure occurred while executing 
com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
```

**Que puede estar ocurriendo? Como lo soluciono? esto me estrezó un poco. Agradezco mucho su lectura**

Comment: Hola Tomas, que estabas intentando hacer, nos podrías dar mas detalles, o intenta eliminar el archivo C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\LearnIn\app\build\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\signing-config.json o quizas corre android studio como administrador.

Comment: Pueda que sea un problema con la firma de la aplicación puedes probar desinstalandola de tu dispositivo físico y volverla a correr desde Android Studio

Comment: Trata de hacerle re-build a la app

Comment: @Diego me funcionó borrando la carpeta. Muchisimas graciass!!!!!

Comment: @TomasM me parece que el error era al sincronizar, después abriste el archivo y este al estar abierto marcaba (Acceso denegado), asegura cerrar todos los archivos y reconstruye el proyecto o elimina en caso extremo /build .

Answer (score 1):

Si revisas el error, muestra que no se puede tener acceso al archivo `signing-config.json` que se encuentra dentro de `\build\intermediates\`, los archivos generados dentro de `\build` son generados cada vez que construyes tu proyecto.

En ocasiones este tipo de problemas es creado por fallas al compilar, **pero en este caso el mensaje  `(Acceso denegado)` indica que probablemente lo tienes abierto y al generar nuevamente tu proyecto este no puede ser regenerado.**

Asegura no tengas el archivo abierto y vuelve a generar nuevamente tu proyecto, en caso de que no funcione realiza un "hard-reset"  eliminando el directorio `/build` de tu proyecto.

Comment: Gracias una vez más Jorge. El error ya lo pude solucionar borrando la carpeta! Si no te molesta, agradecería que pases por esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/322251/android-studio-por-que-tengo-este-error-al-pasar-datos-de-fragment-a-fragment