# Por que tengo este error al pasar datos de fragment a fragment?

Tags: android, data

**Adjunto el error:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.learnin/com.example.ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a01ce (com.example.learnin:id/view_pager) for fragment fragment_perfil_profesor{fe7280c #3 id=0x7f0a01ce}
```

**Descripción:**

Tengo un fragment tabbeado (FRAGMENT "A" con 3 tabs) y dentro de una esas tabs hay otro fragment tabbeado (FRAGMENT "B" con otras 3 tabs). Estoy intentando pasar datos de fragment "A" a "B" por medio de bundles pero obtengo un error.

**Adjunto el código de FRAGMENT "A"**

```
if(getArguments() != null){
        String nombre, url_foto;
        nombre = getArguments().getString("nombre");
        url_foto = getArguments().getString("url_foto");

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("nombre",nombre);
        bundle.putString("url_foto",url_foto);

        Fragment fragment = new fragment_perfil();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        //AL COMENTAR ESTAS DOS LÍNEAS, EL ERROR SE VA PERO LOS DATOS NO SE PASAN AL FRAGMENT "B"
        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.view_pager,fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
```

**Aclaración:** El FRAGMENT "A" intenta pasar datos que anteriormente una actividad ya le pasó a el (Adjunto el código al final)

**Adjunto el código de FRAGMENT "B"**

```
if(getArguments() != null){
        String nombre, url_foto;
        nombre_profesor = getArguments().getString("nombre");
        url_foto = getArguments().getString("url_foto");

        Glide.with(getActivity()).load(url_foto).error(R.drawable.img_error).placeholder(R.drawable.img_loading).into(img_foto);
        txt_nombre_usuario.setText(nombre);
    }
```

**Adjunto el código de la actividad que les mencioné arriba la cual le pasa los datos a FRAGMENT "A".**

```
            String nombre = datos.getText().toString();
            String url_foto = url.getText().toString();

            //NOMBRE DE FRAGMENT "A"
            fragment = new fragment_contenedor_perfil();

            bundle.putString("nombre",nombre);
            bundle.putString("url_foto",url_foto);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);

            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

**Desde ya, muchas gracias por leer!**

Answer (score 0):

Seria de bueno que pongas el log del error.

Pero la manera para pasar datos sin complicaciones es a través de clases estaticas.

```
static class Data {

  static DataType mydata
}
```

Antes de hacer un replace add o show con el fragment manager actualiza los datos y en el fragment ya los tienes.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [ask], recuerda que las aclaraciones se realizan como comentario, saludos.

Comment: No entendí nada, español?. Solo veo respuestas y comentarios, Una no se puede por que necesito tener 50 puntos, solo me queda respuestas.

Comment: Revisa por favor [¿Por qué necesito 50 puntos de reputación para comentar? ¿Qué alternativa tengo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/586/por-qu%c3%a9-necesito-50-puntos-de-reputaci%c3%b3n-para-comentar-qu%c3%a9-alternativa-tengo).